# Removing all spaces during tokenization

Tags: c++

How can I remove all spaces between tokens in the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s[3] = {"a 1", "b    2", "c  3"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        stringstream ss(s[i]);
        string tok;
        while(getline(ss, tok, ' '))  // <-- need to fix
        {
            cout << tok << ".";  // <-- need to fix
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is

```
a.1
b.2
c.3
```

But the code generates

```
a.1.
b....2.
c..3.
```

Comment: Can you just use `<<` and ignore all the whitespace in string?

Comment: Replace `while(getline(ss, tok, ' '))` with `while(ss >> tok)`

Comment: Since you put a `'.'` after each `tok` I would expect `a.1.` not `a.1`. Do you really mean `a.1` and not `a.1.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use formatted input from the stream instead of `std::getline`. Formatted input skips whitespaces by default:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string s[3] = {"a 1", "b    2", "c  3"};

    for (const auto& str : s) {
        std::istringstream ss(str);

        if (std::string tok; ss >> tok) {
            // at least one token read, print it
            std::cout << tok;

            // then read the rest and prepend them with '.' instead:
            while (ss >> tok) {
                std::cout << '.' << tok;
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a.1
b.2
c.3
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K1Tj3MGcP)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::regex_replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) for this, unless there is a particular reason you are using stringstream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s[3] = {"a 1", "b    2", "c  3"};
    for (std::string& str : s) {
        str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex{"\\s+"}, ".");
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/zW196M1cT)

```
a.1
b.2
c.3
```

Comment: With the obligatory comment that `<regex>` is absolutely miserable if you care about performance even a little. Still, this is my preferred solution.

Comment: @sweenish Putting the `string` in a  `stringstream` and extracting from that isn't very efficient either. It's good for making something simple quckly, just like using regex, but I'd not use any of them where performance matters.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Meh. There are better regex libraries. That's really all I was getting at.  Even the worst alternative is at least 2x faster than `<regex>`. I wasn't talking about "performance is king" code at all.

Comment: @sweenish :-) Oh, is it really that bad? I've only used it in a real program once and that was to give the user an option to do free searches in memory areas. It did the job but it's good to know that if performance is an issue, there are faster alternatives. Do you know if  the g++, clang++ and MSVC `std` library implementations of `<regex>` are equally bad? I was following the development of compiletime `constexpr` regexes for awhile but I haven't kept updated lately.

Comment: I believe they are all pretty bad. I recall a post on r/cpp benchmarking various regex libraries, and it was bad news for `std::regex`. I can't find it quickly, though. And that's assuming it still exists given the drama over on reddit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this split function I wrote earlier.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

// it is always useful to build up a library of functions
// regex as said is awfully slow. And splitting (or tokenizing)
// strings is needed often.
// split uses string_views on the original string
// so keep the original string in memory
//
auto split(std::string_view string, std::string_view delimiters)
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> substrings;

    if ((string.size() == 0ul))
    {
        return substrings;
    }

    if (delimiters.size() == 0ul)
    {
        substrings.emplace_back(string);
        return substrings;
    }

    auto start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters);
    auto end_pos = start_pos;
    auto max_length = string.length();

    while (start_pos < max_length)
    {
        end_pos = std::min(max_length, string.find_first_of(delimiters, start_pos));

        if (end_pos != start_pos)
        {
            substrings.emplace_back(&string[start_pos], end_pos - start_pos);
            start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end_pos);
        }
    }

    return substrings;
}


// using namespace std; <== do not do this.
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings{ "a 1", "b    2", "c  3" };
    for (const auto& string : strings)
    {
        // this will split to sets of tokens {"a", "1"}, {"b","2"} and {"c", "3"}
        auto tokens = split(string," ");
        std::cout << "tokens : ";

        // output the (cleaned up) tokens
        for (const auto& token : tokens)
        {
            std::cout << token << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```